Multivariate Time Series Problem with Variable Input Size : Classification
I have a multivariate time series data. Each sample has features f0 to f100 , with 24 time steps. Some thing like this:

The x-axis is the 24 time steps and the y-axis are the 100 features.
The challenge is , each sample has an uncertain number of features occurring at the bottom , that are all nans.
This is a classification task , where samples in a given class may have variable sizes like this. They are in the same class , because when plotted as a heatmap , the bigger samples appear similar to the smaller ones. Something like this:

Please point me towards a deep learning approach using RNNs or LSTM that can handle this problem. May be there's a sane approach to mask the nan values and still extract the relevant features for a class where the inputs may vary like this.
